# Using Coda Hale Yammer Metrics library in Websphere Application Server 7

Tags: java, websphere, metrics

I am trying to add metrics library to existing webservice on WAS 7. I am getting below error

Error 404: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0203E: Servlet [AdminServlet]: com.yammer.metrics.reporting.AdminServlet was found, but is missing another required class. SRVE0206E: This error typically implies that the servlet was originally compiled with classes which cannot be located by the server. SRVE0187E: Check your class path to ensure that all classes required by the servlet are present.SRVE0210I: This problem can be debugged by recompiling the servlet using only the classes in the application's runtime class path SRVE0234I

What are the other run-time dependencies required for metrics-servlet-2.2.0?

I have metrics-core-2.2.0.jar and metrics-servlet-2.2.0.jar in my WEB-INF\lib folder.

Threads, ping and healthcheck servlets work fine.

Comment: I have the exact same problem did you find any solution?

Comment: No Sorry didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think your missing some more required jars, are you not using maven or gradle for `dependency management` 
Please refer here to know all required jars that `metrics-servlet-2.2.0.jar` depends on. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.yammer.metrics/metrics-servlets/3.0.0-BETA1

My suggestion is, it is always difficult to maintain dependencies without Maven/Gradle or any other build tools :).